# building cassandra test cases failing

Tags: ant, build, cassandra

I am trying to build cassandra binaries from source and when I try to compile unit test cases, some of them give me errors. I tried versions `2.0.14`, `2.1.4` and `2.1.5` with `ubuntu 14.04` and `Java 7` as well as `Java 8`. This is the message I get after building the test cases:

```
BUILD FAILED
/opt/cassandra/build.xml:1139: Some test bucket 0 test(s) failed.
Total time: 17 minutes 13 seconds
Buildfile: `/opt/cassandra/build.xml`
```

Am I doing something wrong? This is how I am trying to build:

- ant
- ant build
- ant build-test
- ant test
- ant artifacts

Comment: Posting only "build failed" and the build.xml line number, without the precise version you built, can only leave someone to guess what your issue might be. If you could update this with the actual build errors, perhaps then someone could help with some better details. Additionally, are you building from git or src.tar.gz, Oracle or OpenJDK 7/8 (all of which should work OK, given a sane build environment)? Edit: start with just `ant` which is really `ant jar` - if you can't build the jar, trying test, etc. is rather pointless, since they require `jar`.

Comment: Since I hadn't run unit tests from a src.tar.gz for a while, I figured out that your line 1139 error was from cassandra 2.1.4, so I went ahead and grabbed the src tar and ran it. It ran fine for me on Oracle JDK 7 - https://gist.github.com/mshuler/907e9fc9a47e966360c8

Comment: I am building from git and I am using Oracle JDK

Comment: Please, paste the entire output somewhere.

Comment: Here is the entire output:  http://txs.io/VY1b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[junit] Testsuite: org.apache.cassandra.utils.BitSetTest
[junit] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.075 sec
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: compareBitSets(org.apache.cassandra.utils.BitSetTest):    Caused an ERROR
[junit] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/dict/words (No such file or directory)
[junit] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/dict/words (No such file or directory)
[junit]     at org.apache.cassandra.utils.KeyGenerator$WordGenerator.reset(KeyGenerator.java:137)
[junit]     at org.apache.cassandra.utils.KeyGenerator$WordGenerator.<init>(KeyGenerator.java:126)
[junit]     at org.apache.cassandra.utils.BitSetTest.compareBitSets(BitSetTest.java:50)
[junit] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/dict/words (No such file or directory)
[junit]     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
[junit]     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
[junit]     at org.apache.cassandra.utils.KeyGenerator$WordGenerator.reset(KeyGenerator.java:135)
[junit]
[junit]
[junit] Test org.apache.cassandra.utils.BitSetTest FAILED
```

There's your error. The test is looking for `/usr/share/dict/words`.

`apt-get install wamerican`